# Add rows inside added row

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to create content type which can be used to add Workouts. Content type has fields: Exercise, Set and Reps.

First user chooses Exercise (this is autocomplete field). Then he can add Set(s) to thise exercise (unlimited amount of sets can be added). Every Set should be added by clicking Add new row. For every set user can add reps.

Then User can add second Exercise and sets and reps to it. Etc.

See picture:

[image: Exercise]

I have tried to use [Multifield](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield) -module, but it does not allow multifield inside multifield.

Any suggestions how to achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: have you tried this. Create a field collection field with unlimited values in content type and then create a field inside field collection with unlimited values?

Comment: @hene Is this a form or just a content type for backend user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.

Create a field of type field_collection inside your content type with unlimited values.

Then in your field collection create a field or group of fields with unlimited values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module?